# How to configure CruiseControl.Net for Windows Authentication?

Tags: security, cruisecontrol, windows-authentication

I am using CruiseControl.Net for continuous integration which is now accessing the dashboard through login plugin, which in turn is authenticating and authorizing after verifying it with a set of users saved as XML file in the CruiseControl.Net server.

Now, i need to bring in Windows Authentication to the system whereby which CruiseControl.Net server webdashboard when accessed from a client machine(local machine associated with a common server), would be authenticated and be authorized to access the  CruiseControl.Net features based on the authority of the logged in users.

Kindly guide me to go ahead with this, appreciate all kinds of resources that would be helpful for achieving this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a better question for serverfault.

Comment: I just posted it in serverfault.Wish somebody will help me soon.